# Unable to read xml with XPath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I need to parse content.xml file in XMind package.
File looks like this

```
<xmap-content xmlns="urn:xmind:xmap:xmlns:content:2.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL   /Format" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="2.0">

   <sheet id="sdfasdfsdf">
      <title> Sheet1 </title>
   </sheet>

   <sheet id="fgasdfgasr">
       <title> Sheet2 </title>
   </sheet>
<xmap-content>
```

I need to get list of title of all sheets.

I am using `XPathExpression expr = navigator.Compile("//sheet");`
but i guess its not working
what to do. any suggestion or code will do.
thnx in advance.

Comment: how to get `<title>` value once i have `XPathNavigator` for a given `<sheet>` ... well i am iterating using `XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("//xm:sheet", manager);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML has defined default namespace: `urn:xmind:xmap:xmlns:content:2.0`. So you need to pass it to your XML engine with prefix, then use expression:

```
//ns:sheet
```

or another way:

```
//*[local-name() = 'sheet']
```

Comment: how do i pass default namespace to xml engine. using XPath

Comment: @j4m4l, using `XmlNamespaceManager`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tywd160x.aspx

Comment: `XmlNamespaceManager manager = new`     `XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);`    
`manager.AddNamespace("xm", "urn:xmind:xmap:xmlns:content:2.0");`    

`XPathExpression expression = navigator.Compile("/xm:sheet");`     
`XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("/xm:sheet", manager);`    
`XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("/xm:sheet", manager);`      i am using following code but still not working?

Comment: @j4m4l, try `//xm:sheet` instead of `/xm:sheet`

Comment: thnx a lot ...    but i need a ask one more thing, how to get `<title>` value once i have `XPathNavigator` for a given `<sheet>`

Comment: @j4m4l, If you current node is `sheet`, you can use `xm:title`

Comment: Thnx a lot @Kirill, u r life savior

Answer (score 0):

try

```
XPathExpression expr =  navigator.Compile("xmap-content/sheet");
```

EDIT:

```
string st = @"<xmap-content xmlns=""urn:xmind:xmap:xmlns:content:2.0"" xmlns:fo=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL   /Format"" xmlns:svg=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" xmlns:xhtml=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" xmlns:xlink=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"" version=""2.0"">

            <sheet id=""sdfasdfsdf"">
                <title> Sheet1 </title>
            </sheet>

            <sheet id=""fgasdfgasr"">
                <title> Sheet2 </title>
            </sheet>
        </xmap-content>";

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(st);

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable); 

manager.AddNamespace("xm", "urn:xmind:xmap:xmlns:content:2.0"); 

var titles = document.SelectNodes("//xm:sheet/xm:title", manager);
```